# How do I compile libtheora

Tags: macos, xcode

### Environment

- OS X 10.10, Yosemite
- Xcode 6.1.1
- Downloaded the library from [xiph.org/downloads](http://www.xiph.org/downloads/)

I tried `.configure`:

```
libtheora$ sudo ./configure
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin14.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for doxygen... false
configure: WARNING: *** doxygen not found, API documentation will not be built
checking for pdflatex... no
checking for bibtex... no
checking for fig2dev... no
configure: WARNING: *** Format Specification will not built.
checking for ld used by gcc... (cached) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... (cached) no
checking how to control symbol export... -exported_symbols_list
checking for pkg-config... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for OGG... yes
checking for VORBIS... no
checking for Vorbis... no
*** Could not run Vorbis test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means Vorbis was incorrectly installed
*** or that you have moved Vorbis since it was installed.
checking for sdl-config... no
checking for SDL - version >= 0.11.0... no
*** The sdl-config script installed by SDL could not be found
*** If SDL was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the SDL_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to sdl-config.
configure: WARNING: *** Unable to find SDL -- Not compiling example players ***
checking sys/soundcard.h usability... no
checking sys/soundcard.h presence... no
checking for sys/soundcard.h... no
checking soundcard.h usability... no
checking soundcard.h presence... no
checking for soundcard.h... no
checking machine/soundcard.h usability... no
checking machine/soundcard.h presence... no
checking for machine/soundcard.h... no
configure: WARNING: OSS audio support not found -- not compiling player_example
checking for PNG... yes
configure: Vorbis missing, cannot build example encoder
checking for library containing ftime... no
checking for getopt_long... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating lib/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'lib/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'include/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating include/theora/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'include/theora/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'examples/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'doc/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating doc/Doxyfile
config.status: creating doc/spec/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'doc/spec/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'tests/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating m4/Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'm4/Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating libtheora.spec
config.status: creating theora.pc
config.status: creating theora-uninstalled.pc
config.status: creating theoradec.pc
config.status: creating theoradec-uninstalled.pc
config.status: creating theoraenc.pc
config.status: creating theoraenc-uninstalled.pc
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

------------------------------------------------------------------------
  libtheora 1.1.1:  Automatic configuration OK.

  General configuration:

    Encoding support: ........... yes
    Floating point support: ..... yes
    Assembly optimization: ...... 32 bit x86
    Debugging telemetry: ........ no
    Build example code: ......... yes
    API Documentation: .......... no
    Format Documentation: ....... no

  Installation paths:

    libtheora: ................... /usr/local/lib
    C header files: .............. /usr/local/include/theora
    Documentation: ............... /usr/local/share/doc/libtheora

  Building:

    Type 'make' to compile libtheora.

    Type 'make install' to install libtheora.

    Type 'make check' to run test suite (Valgrind testing not enabled)

  Example programs will be built but not installed.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

…and then `make`:

```
libtheora$ sudo make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in lib
source='apiwrapper.c' object='apiwrapper.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/apiwrapper.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/apiwrapper.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/sh ../depcomp \
    /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include   -I/usr/local/include   -Wall -Wno-parentheses -O3 -fforce-addr -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -funroll-loops  -c -o apiwrapper.lo `test -f 'apiwrapper.c' || echo './'`apiwrapper.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wno-parentheses -O3 -fforce-addr -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -funroll-loops -c apiwrapper.c -MT apiwrapper.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/apiwrapper.TPlo  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/apiwrapper.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fforce-addr'
make[2]: *** [apiwrapper.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any pointer is most welcome.

Comment: Use a packaging system like macports, fink, home-brew where the porters have worked out the issues. I would also check your autoconf etc as the build i386-apple-darwin14.1.0 looks wrong as that I think is 32 bit only

Comment: Try removing `-fforce-addr` flag from `configure` file.

Comment: Yes you are right Mark, I should have seen that `i386-apple-darwin14.1.0`. It doesn't look correct indeed. I am trying `brew install theora`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug. It was fixed on **macports** by removing `-fforce-addr` flag. Here's [the fix](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/multimedia/libtheora/files/patch-configure.diff?rev=118032).

Remove this flag from `configure` file and repeat the operation.

If You want to build for different architecture, pass params to `configure`. For example, to change arch to 64bit - on my machine I'll do:

```
./configure --target=x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 --host=x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
```

To get architecture check `gcc -v`.

Comment: sounds like a reasonable solution indeed, however I am still concerned about what Mark pointed out, the `i386-apple-darwin14.1.0` in the log indicate that their might be other issues. I opted for `brew`, I will update my post accordingly. Again thanks you

Comment: I've added info about changing architecture. `brew`/`macports`/`fink` is indeed safer solution, but if You'd like to change the sources, then that's the way to do it.

Comment: yeah indeed I actually like your answer, because I may need to stick to an older version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Opted for `brew install theora`, which seems to have installed the library correctly. I have some `brew link` errors but they are due to conflicting libs, that I had previously installed

```
$ brew install theora
==> Installing dependencies for theora: libogg, libvorbis
==> Installing theora dependency: libogg
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/libogg-1.3.2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libogg-1.3.2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink include/ogg/config_types.h
Target /usr/local/include/ogg/config_types.h
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/ogg/config_types.h'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite libogg

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run libogg

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/include/ogg/config_types.h
/usr/local/include/ogg/ogg.h
/usr/local/include/ogg/os_types.h
/usr/local/share/aclocal/ogg.m4
/usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.6.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libogg.a
/usr/local/lib/libogg.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.6.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ogg.pc
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libogg/1.3.2: 95 files, 672K
==> Installing theora dependency: libvorbis
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/libvorbis-1.3.4.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libvorbis-1.3.4.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink include/vorbis/codec.h
Target /usr/local/include/vorbis/codec.h
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/vorbis/codec.h'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite libvorbis

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run libvorbis

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/include/vorbis/codec.h
/usr/local/include/vorbis/vorbisenc.h
/usr/local/include/vorbis/vorbisfile.h
/usr/local/share/aclocal/vorbis.m4
/usr/local/lib/libvorbis.0.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libvorbis.0.4.3.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libvorbis.a
/usr/local/lib/libvorbis.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libvorbis.0.4.3.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.2.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.2.0.6.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.a
/usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.2.0.6.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libvorbisfile.3.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libvorbisfile.3.3.2.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libvorbisfile.a
/usr/local/lib/libvorbisfile.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libvorbisfile.3.3.2.dylib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/vorbis.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/vorbisenc.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/vorbisfile.pc
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libvorbis/1.3.4: 162 files, 2.7M
==> Installing theora
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/theora-1.1.1.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring theora-1.1.1.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/theora/1.1.1: 93 files, 2.3M
```